# Conditional delete across multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One of them contains files, the other one actions:

```
|Files    |                  |Actions     |
|---------|                  |------------|
|FileID   |                  |ActionID    |
|Filename |                  |ActionDate  |
|...      |                  |...         |
|---------|                  |------------|
```

One file can have several actions. Those actions happened at a certain date.

Every now and then I want to delete all files and its actions. But only if one of the actions of that file is older than - say - 1 year.

For example:

File 1 has 2 actions: Both actions happened a week ago. Do not delete

File 2 has 2 actions: Both actions happened 10 years ago. Delete

File 3 has 2 actions: One of them happened 10 years ago, the other one half a year ago. Delete

I would love to do that without having to do it in several steps. (Like selecting stuff in my perl script first and then iterate over those to delete them or whatever)

If this is too easy I can provide further challenge:
There is another table, lets call it 'State'. One State can have multiple actions again and i also want to delete all the states that are referenced by the actions that are going to be deleted.

Any hints on how to do this highly appreciated!

**edit**
oh my, I just realized that deleting from multiple tables at once is highly discouraged, especially when dealing with big amounts of data.
I assume this means there is no (decent) way around doing this within sql, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files and action you first need to find out the files whose one of action is a year later this can be done using below query

```
select *,
sum(ActionDate < now() - interval 1 year) need_to_delete
from 
Actions 
group by FileID
  having need_to_delete >0
```

This will give you the file ids which need to be delete from the database

### [Select Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d05e2/1)

Second you need multi-delete query joined with above query to delete from multiple tables in single query

```
delete f.*,a.* from files f
join Actions a
on(f.FileID = a.FileID)
join (
  select *,
sum(ActionDate < now() - interval 1 year) need_to_delete
from 
Actions 
group by FileID
  having need_to_delete >0
) fa
on(f.FileID = fa.FileID)
```

### [Delete Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33294/1)

For deletion of states above query will help you and i am leaving it to